# If I know the class type of an Enum, how can I get a list of the values?

Tags: apex, list, type, enum, refactoring

I have the following method:

```
    public XAP_ENUM_EnumConverter put(Type enumType, XAP_ENUM_EnumWrapper enumWrapper) {
        ENUM_WRAPPERS_BY_TYPE_MAP.put(enumType, enumWrapper);
        return this;
    }
```

which i can invoke in a constructor like this:

```
    private ALP_CONX_ColourHelper(XAP_ENUM_EnumConverter converter) {
        this.converter = converter;
        this.converter.put(ALP_CONX_Colour.class, new XAP_ENUM_EnumWrapper(ALP_CONX_Colour.values()));
    }
```

Where `ALP_CONX_Colour` is an enum, e.g.

```
public enum ALP_CONX_Colour {
    BLACK,
    WHITE,
    NONE
}
```

A helper for a different enum would have a similar constructor.

But this rather redundant, as the name of the enum-class is required to provide both paramenters and this should always be consistent.  It would make no sense to have a Type for "Colours" and a List for "Shapes".  So, I'd like to refactor this function to one parameter like:

```
    public XAP_ENUM_EnumConverter put(Type enumType) {
        List<Object> enumList = this.createEnumList(enumType);
        XAP_ENUM_EnumWrapper enumWrapper = new XAP_ENUM_EnumWrapper(enumList);
        ENUM_WRAPPERS_BY_TYPE_MAP.put(enumType, enumWrapper);
        return this;
    }


    private List<Object> createEnumList(Type enumType) {
         // What do I need to do here?
         return ???
    }
```

Is it possible to do this?
If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

There is no generic, dynamic approach that will work for all types. Probably the best you can do if you want to avoid maintaining a map is to use a `switch` statement.

```
switch on String.valueOf(enumType)
{
    when 'MyCustomEnum'
    {
        return MyCustomEnum.values();
    }
    when 'MyClass.Enum'
    {
        return MyClass.Enum.values
    }
    when 'System.LoggingLevel'
    {
        return LoggingLevel.values();
    }
    when else
    {
        return new List<String>();
        // alternatively consider to be an error case
    }
}
```

Probably slower than just calling `values()` concretely; I wouldn consider such an implementation to be of questionable benefit.

Comment: Switches perform well enough (better than if-else chains), but I agree that this is basically more trouble than its worth.

Comment: I'm not trying to avoid a map, but rather avoid redundant information in the method invocations I use to populate the map.  Currently, lets say I am only interested in enums which are like 'MyCustomEnum', ignoring the other possibilities.  Is there a way I can handle just those dynamically?

Comment: No, you can only interact with `Enum` concretely. You have to build your own layer on top if you want any dynamic functionality.

Comment: Building my own layer is what I'm doing, but I was hoping it would be possible to do it in a more intelligent way.  Sigh.

Comment: Not much room for elegance or cleverness. If you want it you just brute force it together. Tedious stuff, though straightforward.

Comment: What if I flipped this question:  If I have a homogenous list of objects where all the members are enums of a particular type (e.g. Colour), would I be able to somehow determine the type from a member of the list?

Comment: Only by calling instanceof against a concrete type. That comparison also can't be dynamic. :/